# How to handle the callback with MagicMock

Tags: python, python-mock, magicmock

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock, MagicMock
import time

wait = False

def pushback_callback(self, res):
  print("Received callback")
  wait = True
  
def pushback_fcn(callback):
  print("pushback_fcn")
  
def execute():
  pushback_fcn(pushback_callback)
  while wait == False:
      time.sleep(5)
      
  print("done")
            
#********* Test code ************#
pushback_fcn = MagicMock()
execute()
```

As test code never call the callback, wait value is False always hence the test code wait forever.  Is there any way we can get the function pointer form MagicMock?

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar code to test mocking a function that receives a callback. Install and run `pytest` to test it out.

The way the callback is mocked is by using `@patch` and `side_effect` ([documentation about how patch and side_effect work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class))

The script includes 2 tests, one without the mock and one with it (changing the value sent through the callback from `done` to `mocked`).

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import threading
import time

event = threading.Event()
result = "pending"


def on_finished(msg):
    global result
    result = msg


def async_fn(callback):
    time.sleep(1)
    event.set()
    callback("done")


def execute():
    async_fn(on_finished)
    event.wait()
    print(f"done with result: {result}")

# ============================================================
# Tests


def test_without_mock():
    execute()
    assert result == "done"


@patch("test_mock_fn_with_callback.async_fn")
def test_with_mock(async_fn):
    async_fn.side_effect = lambda callback: callback("mocked")
    execute()
    assert result == "mocked"
```